# How to select rows from a dataframe using a list with different values?

Tags: r

I want to select a subset of a larger data.frame using a list of ID numbers. ID is a column with unique numerical values, but does not correspond to row number. All of the basic tutorials I've seen for subsetting data presume a single value for selecting the row. e.g.

```
fires <- subset(emergencies, ID == 2, select = c("type","frequency", "casualties"))
```

This isn't what I want.

How do you select rows for ID 2,3,7 and 8, not just 2?

I've tried a variety of things. Most recently:

```
fires <- subset(emergencies, ID == c(2,3,7,8), select = c("type","frequency", "casualties"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use `dplyr`, the key is to filter cases whose ID values are found `%in%` the given vector.

```
library(dplyr)

emergencies |>
    filter(ID %in% c(2,3,7,8)) |>
    select(all_of(c("type", "frequency", "casualties"))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example dataframe:**

```
emergencies <- data.frame(
    ID = c(-1, 10, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'a'),
    type = c("fire", "fire", "medical", "police", "fire", "medical", "police", "fire"),
    frequency = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
    casualties = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80)
)
```

**The code:**

```
fires <- subset(emergencies, ID %in% c(-1, 10, 'a'), select = c("type", "frequency", "casualties"))
```

**Test output:**

```
print(fires)


  type frequency casualties
1 fire         1         10
2 fire         2         20
8 fire         8         80
```

Comment: Thank you! Been looking at tutorials for hours.

Comment: @VegetationLife The important concept, I think, it that the expression `ID %in% c(-1, 10, 'a')` returns a logical vector with as many entries as your data frame has rows - in the above example `c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)` - this is then used to tell which rows to keep.  This general concept can be used over and over again in R.